# Remove duplicate elements of a list when a different element matches - Python

Tags: python, list

- Two lists of lists, h & i.
- The length of h[0] is equal to h[1] and equal to h[2].  Same goes for i[0], i[1], and i[2].
- The length of h[0] may not be equal to i[0].
- When h[0][x] = i[0][y], "compare" h[2][x] & i[2][y].
- The function "compare" means the following:

  1. Split both x & y into lists when encountering a '\n' with x.split('\n') and y.split('\n').
  2. For each element of x.split('\n') and y.split('\n'), remove duplicates with list_difference.
  3. Store that result in new list results.

Non-working code below

```
def list_difference(list1, list2):
    """Uses list1 as the reference, returns list of items not in list2."""
    diff_list = []
    for item in list1:
        if not item in list2:
            diff_list.append(item)
    return diff_list


h=[['match','meh'],['0','1'],['remove\n0\n12','1']]
i=[['match','ignore0','ignore1'],['0','2','3'],['1\nremove','2','3']]
result = result(h,i)

# result should be:
# result = [['match','meh'],['0','1'],['0','1']]

# code not working:
results  = []
for l in h:
    for p in i:
        if l[0] == p[0]:
            results.append(list_difference(l[2].split('\n'), p[2].split('\n')))

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<pyshell#19>", line 4, in <module>
#     results.append(list_difference(l[2].split('\n'), p[2].split('\n')))
# IndexError: list index out of range
```

Getting closer:

```
for l0, l2 in h[0], h[2]:
    for p0, p2 in i[0], i[2]:
        if l0 == p0:
            results.append(list_difference(l2.split('\n'), p2.split('\n')))
print results
# [['h0_1']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but is probably not the most efficient or pythonic code.

```
import string
def list_difference(list1, list2):
    """Uses list1 as the reference, returns list of items not in list2."""
    diff_list = []
    for item in list1:
        if not item in list2:
            diff_list.append(item)
    return diff_list

def list_in_list_newline_diff(h, i):
    """When h[0] equals i[0], diffs h[2] against i[2], returns diff'd h."""
    new_h = [[],[],[]]
    hh = zip(h[0], h[1], h[2])
    ii = zip(i[0], i[1], i[2])
    for hi, hd, hr in hh:
        # print 'host %s\n%s' % (hi, hr.split('\n'))
        for pi, pd, pr in ii:
                if hi == pi:
                #print 'prev %s\n%s' % (pi, pr.split('\n'))
                    hr = string.join(list_difference(hr.split('\n'), pr.split('\n')), sep='\n')
        if hr == '':
            continue
        new_h[0].append(hi)
        new_h[1].append(hd)
        new_h[2].append(hr)
    return new_h
```